# Is there a prescribed posture for prayer?

Tags: sin

I want to know if it is wrong to lie in bed and pray. I know we should kneel and pray but when I do that I lose focus and is not as meaningful as when I am in bed so is it okay to lie in bed and give a meaningful prayer or should I just focus more and be patient until I get used to kneeling on my knees

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Christianity SE! Good news! This [has been asked before](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/can-we-pray-from-any-position) so you don't have to wait on an answer!

Comment: @RyanFrame ... [Just wanted to say...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11150504#11150504)